# Create a library when using PlatformIO

Tags: library, platformio

**(1)** I'm trying to work with libraries in PlatformIO format", for [image: example], of a library, located in Arduino's `libraries`, where code is llocated under `\src` directry.

**(2)** Any other library, not it "PlatformIO format" as I call it, has to contain inside `libraries/EXMPLE` lib a `EXMPLE.h`, and `EXMPLE.cpp` file.

**(3)** Now, when I try to create a "PlatromIO format" library (since I want to move to PlatfromIO)
compilation fails, saying `.h` file was not found (an error you would get since `.h` `.cpp` was not located in their parent directory), as noted in **2** . see library `ABCD` in [image: snapshot] (which contains only library structures).

Appreciate any help

Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing "1.5.x" format libraries, not "PlatformIO". This arrangement for a library was created for Arduino IDE version 1.5.0.

The critical part of this library format is the `library.properties` file which describes the library, and also identifies it as being a library (and which you seem to be lacking). The format of the file is described [here](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/0.20/library-specification/).

Comment: Well I suspected so, but it have to an url to GitHub ?

Comment: @guyd No, but if there is a web page associated with the library it should be included. It doesn't have to be github, that's just an example. I think `url=` is optional anyway.